# HTML Email TD's stacking

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to create an HTML Email with a table, and from what I've been reading, my `TD`, `TR`, and `TABLE`s need to be `display:block` in order to work, be responsive etc. However, when I put the cells in the document they stack instead of appearing linearly.

Sorry, it's so long. I've been playing with different solutions to try to get this "responsive" thing to work for this email, but i'm a bit stumped.

```css
  /* Basics */
body {
    Margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
    Margin:0 !important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
    max-width: 600px;
    Margin: 0 auto;
}

table[class="magic"],
table[class="magic"] tbody,
table[class="magic"] tr,
table[class="magic"] td {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Y! and Outlook bg image fix */
tr[class=GradeHead] {
width: 100% !important;
height: 198px;
background-image:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/5827ac1b-050b-4752-9f9f-728e05e3170b.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-position: 0px 6px !important;
background-size:cover;
}

tr .g-row{
width: 100% !important;
height: auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-size:cover;
background-position: -2px center !important;
display:table-row;
}

tr .g-row-2{
background-image:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/535bc2e7-194c-4484-b47e-d8ecd81659a1.png');
}

tr .g-row-3{
background-image:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/573b935e-64d4-43d4-b29c-aa3cc0661dbf.png');
}

tr .g-row-4{
background-image:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/535bc2e7-194c-4484-b47e-d8ecd81659a1.png');
}

td[class=option] {
width: 300px !important;
height: auto !important;
display: table-cell;
}

td[class=cover] {
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-position: center !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: auto;
}

td .boys {
background-image: url('img/row-1-bubbles.png') !important;
}

td .ship {
background-image: url('img/row-2-ship.png') !important;
}

td .resort {
background-image: url('img/row-3-resort.png') !important;
}
/* iphone X Media call */
  @media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
    and (device-pixel-ratio : 3) { }
    
/* iphone 7,8 Media call */
 @media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 667px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
    and (device-pixel-ratio : 2) { }
    
/* iphone 6 Plus, 6S Plus, 7 Plus, 8 Plus Media call */
 @media only screen 
    and (device-width : 414px) 
    and (device-height : 736px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
 and (device-pixel-ratio : 3) { }

  body{
   background-color:#fff;
  }
  *{
   font-family:Futura,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  }
  p{
   color:#929292;
   font-size:18px;
  }
  .plus{
   font-size:2em;
   padding:20px 10px;
   border-radius:30px;
  }
  a{
   text-decoration:none;
   color:inherit;
  }
  #footer a{
   text-decoration:underline;
  }
  #footer p{
   color:#c5b9ac;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  .btn-pink{
   color:#fff;
   background-color:#fa0375;
   display:block;
   padding:15px 5px;
   border-radius:30px;
   font-size:22px;
   text-align:center;
  }
  .btn-white{
   color:#fff;
   border:2px solid #fff;
   font-size:18px;
   display:block;
   margin:10px 25px;
   padding:10px 15px;
   text-align:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   border-radius:30px;
  }
  .btn-purp{
   color:#fff;
   background-color:#69034c;
   display:block;
   padding:15px 5px;
   border-radius:30px;
   font-size:20px;
   text-align:center;
   margin:25px 70px;
  }
  h3{
   color:#fff;
   font-size:21px;
   font-weight:normal;
  }
  table,tr,td{
   border:none;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   padding:0;
   border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
   border-style:none;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
  td h3,td p{
   margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<table style="width:600px;height:1726px;table-layout:fixed;display:block;border:none;clear:both;" class="magic" width="600">
<tr class="GradeHead" style="height:198px;background:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/5827ac1b-050b-4752-9f9f-728e05e3170b.png') no-repeat 0px 6px;">
 <td colspan="4" style="height:198px; width:600px;">
   <h2 style="display:none;">You're always up to speed</h2>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr style="" class="g-row g-row-2">
 <td class="option" colspan="2" width="300" style="width:300px;text-align:center;" >
   <h3>HEADLINE </h3>
   <p>COPY</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn-white">Explore</a>
 </td>
 <td colspan="2" class="cover boys" width="300" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/8d7b0292-bd08-4b33-87aa-0f56c86b24e3.png') no-repeat;">
  
 </td>
</tr>
<tr style="" class="g-row g-row-3">
 <td colspan="2" width="300" class="cover ship" style="width:300px;height:300px;) no-repeat;">
  
 </td>
 <td  class="option" colspan="2" width="300" style="width:300px;text-align:center;">
               <h3>HEADLINE </h3>
   <p>COPY</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn-white">Explore</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr style="" class="g-row g-row-4">
 <td class="option" colspan="2" width="300" style="width:300px;text-align:center;">
               <h3>HEADLINE </h3>
   <p>COPY</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn-white">Explore</a>
 </td>
 <td class="cover resort" colspan="2" width="300" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/ecd8b1b9-fed4-42f8-a262-1f769323d7da.png') no-repeat;">      
 </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:180px;">
 <td colspan="4" style="background:url('https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/d176648a-185c-415d-986e-545b427b1812.png') no-repeat 0px -1px;">
   <h2 style="display:none;">Connect with us: @myvacaya</h2>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <a href="https://instagr.am/myvacaya"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/43334793-5066-4ead-accb-a1bfcf81e6b1.png" alt="A well dressed man celebrating"></a>
 </td>   <td>
 <a href="https://twitter.com/myvacaya"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/eaea60f1-f4ba-44f2-9175-789386790126.png" alt="A group of partygoers in the sun" style="margin-bottom: 24px;"></a>
 </td>
 <td>
 <a href="https://facebook.com/myvacaya"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/08329669-dc4e-423d-8769-acb741cf5824.png" alt="A group of mixed race friends at the beach" style="margin-bottom: 24px;"></a>
 </td>
 <td>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTMhOkIDdThzifl_-ly2PAQ"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/88f8ea77021bbc9d2f53d5229/images/3dd02748-8597-42df-8bb4-6817f959337c.png" alt="A woman in a sun hat drinking from a straw" style="margin-bottom: 24px;"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4">
 <a href="https://www.myvacaya.com/discover/faqs/?utm_source=welcome-sub&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=welcome-faqs" class="btn-purp" style="width:300px;margin:15px auto;">Qs? WE'VE GOT As</a>
 <a href="https://myvacaya.com/?utm_source=welcome-sub&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=lets-do-this" class="plus btn-pink" style="width:400px;margin:15px auto;">LET'S DO THIS</a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, I do know that the widths for these cells should be in percent, but when i do put it into percent that the cells just squish up and push off to the left. I have no idea why.
Just trying to tackle one thing at a time. lol

Comment: `display:block` will always push that element to the next line. Have you tried `display:inline-block`? `inline-block` will display elements side by side when there is enough space. The elements will only stack when the document is opened on a smaller screen.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit confused on what you are wanting to do here. Tables for responsive layout are a bit deprecated. Which content do you want in which columns? From what I'm seeing you're using 2 columns. You are over complicating it by using colspan unless you are later going to be putting content in each of the four columns.

Comment: @ChrisHitchcock there is a 4 column in 2nd to last tr here.